# Adding delimited text layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I was using QGIS 2.18 before the update. Adding a delimited text layer was very straightforward. However, in QGIS 3.0 I can do the same process, step by step, but it won't plot.

In summary, the link shows what I was doing in QGIS 2.18: http://www.qgistutorials.com/pt_BR/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html

Comment: I tried it with the csv from your link and for me it works in QGIS 3.0 Have you set the correct CRS and X/Y fields? Do you get any errors in the log messages (check View>Panels>Log Messages) while adding the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I usually have my data like this. Notice that I am using Excel and I save my data as CSV comma delimited.

[image]

You have to use the "Data Source Manager", either by the icon in the GUI or Layer/Data Source Manager. You have to choose the "delimited text" option. This is what you will see:
[image]

Then you have to fill the appripiate fields like:

File name

File format

Geometry Definition. In this one it is mandatory to select the proper Coordinate reference system at "Geometry CRS". My data is lat lon WGS84, so I use EPSG 4326. If your data comes in a projected CRS you must choose the proper EPSG code.

[image]

You will see an example of the way Qgis is understanding your data. This is an example:[image]

Now choose the button add, and thats it. This is the resulting map with the data in the second image:

[image]