# How to generate a layer of points from a database of lat, long using qGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, point

I am a programmer but I am new in QGIS. I have a database of some hundreds of points with lat, long information. It is an excel spreadsheet.

How can I create a layer of points of each lat, long from those data?

Comment: Check this question, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273143/adding-delimited-text-layer-in-qgis/273169#273169

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. tnks