# Converting KML to CSV with QGIS

Tags: kml, csv

I'm currently attempting to to convert a KML database and export in CSV for a research project.
I'm able to load the KML into QGIS but an issue has arisen.

[image]

The points appear perfectly in the mapping layer. However, when I open the attribute table, some of the information in the description field has been cut and the full description is not available. Is it possible to increase the character limit to include all the information in this field?[image]

I am not a technical person and have no programming experience.

Running QGIS 3.8.2.

Comment: Did you try to open the kml with a text-editor like Notepad++ for Windows? Does the missing information show there? KML is able to store more text than what appears on your screenshot - so first check if the information has been cut already in your original KML file. You might also try one of the online converters - just google for "kml to csv"

Comment: Hi,Thanks. I have tried opening the KML in Notepad in the past but will give it another go. I have tried an online KML to CSV converter but it seems to have a problem compiling the information.

Comment: Quick update.

I've managed to convert the KML to an XML using Notepad and Excel. The full descriptions are complete in the original KML.

If I were to add the database to QGIS as a CSV would the descriptions end up being cut down due to a character limit?

Comment: Best is always to just try it: open your CSV in QGIS as a delimited text layer - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273143/adding-delimited-text-layer-in-qgis for details. Be careful with Excel, it often formats your file in a way that is difficult to read by QGIS. Safe your file with an editor and use UTF-8 as encryption.

There should be no practical limitation of lenght in CSV, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189190/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-column-in-csv-file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189190/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-column-in-csv-file

Comment: Brillitant. Thanks. I'll give that a go. CSVs have been pretty stable when I've used QGIS in the past.

Comment: Great. All fixed now. The full descriptions are showing up nicely in QGIS. Thank you for your help.